# Android - Stopping Little Fluffy Location Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-location

I am testing out the really nice `Little Fluffy Location Service` (https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/), but I can't figure out how to stop the service. It seems to continue forever.

**How can this service be stopped, and also started later?**

Answer (score 1):

try this.

`LocationLibrary.stopAlarmAndListener(getApplicationContext());//To Stop Location Updates
LocationLibrary.startAlarmAndListener(getApplicationContext());//To Start Location Updates`